# Connect app to local mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm using this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Soj22OMc98&list=UUY2jb6DjCg50fd1nukZNz-Q) to try and connect an android app to a locally hosted MySQL database. The php script doesn't seem to be the issue as it works fine locally (through internet explorer) and I keep on receiving a null pointer exception causing the app to crash.

The main activity

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.responseTextView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.responseTextView);

    new GetAllCustomerTask().execute(new ApiConnector());

}

public void setTextToTextView(JSONArray jsonArray)
{
    String s  = "";
    for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){

        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            s = s +
                    "Name : "+json.getString("name")+"\n"+
                    "Owner : "+json.getInt("owner")+"\n"+
                    "Species : "+json.getInt("species")+"\n"+
                    "Sex : "+json.getInt("sex")+"\n"+
                    "Birth : "+json.getInt("birth")+"\n"+
                    "Death : "+json.getInt("death")+"\n";
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    this.responseTextView.setText(s);
}

private class GetAllCustomerTask extends AsyncTask<ApiConnector,Long,JSONArray>
{
    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(ApiConnector... params) {

         return params[0].GetAllCustomers();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {

        setTextToTextView(jsonArray);

    }
}
```

ApiConnector class

```
String url = "http://localhost/getallcustomers.php";

    HttpEntity httpEntity = null;

    try
    {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  // Default HttpClient
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONArray jsonArray = null;

    if (httpEntity != null) {
        try {
            String entityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

            Log.e("Entity Response  : ", entityResponse);

            jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponse);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return jsonArray;

}
```

I think the problem may be with the url, but as I said before it seems to be working fine through internet explorer.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: For sure your problem comes from the URL! `localhost` is referring to the local machine, when browsing from IE on your computer it's normal that `localhost` is running correctly. When deployed on your device, `localhost` is referencing your device and not your computer

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I have changed the url to

String url = "http://10.0.2.2/mysql/getallcustomers.php";

however the database is not being displayed and calls a null pointer exception when it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with Android, MySQL or PHP. In my opinion you need to take time to learn the basics of **Computer Network** in order to make communication possible between your computer and your mobile device.

Have a look at this article: [How to connect Android with PHP MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

This article may help you to better understand what your real problem is. Here are the main steps that you need to think about:

- Both machines need to be on the **same network** (LAN)
- The appropriate **port(s)** need to be opened on your computer in order to allow inbound connection (Configuration of your firewall)

Hope this will help you to solve your problem.